# Estimate ETH gas price

Tags: web3js, gas

I need to calculate the "Best" gas and gas prices for my transactions

The term "Best" could be the minimum, average, or maximum available gas

I tried using this API https://ethgasstation.info/json/ethgasAPI.json

But I couldn't find any documentation

somebody, please explain these results

```
{
 "fast": 530,
 "fastest": 530,
 "safeLow": 142,
 "average": 142,
 "block_time": 12.215384615384615,
 "blockNum": 15537392,
 "speed": 0.7801066667730836,
 "safeLowWait": 1.4,
 "avgWait": 1.4,
 "fastWait": 0.5,
 "fastestWait": 0.5,
 "gasPriceRange": {
    "4": 203.6,
    "6": 203.6,
    "8": 203.6,
    "10": 203.6,
    "20": 203.6,
    "30": 203.6,
    "40": 203.6,
    "50": 203.6,
    "60": 203.6,
    "70": 203.6,
    "80": 203.6,
    "90": 203.6,
    "100": 203.6,
    "110": 203.6,
    "120": 203.6,
    "130": 203.6,
    "140": 203.6,
    "142": 1.4,
    "150": 1.3,
    "160": 1.2,
    "170": 1.1,
    "180": 0.9,
    "190": 0.8,
    "210": 0.8,
    "230": 0.7,
    "250": 0.7,
    "270": 0.7,
    "290": 0.7,
    "310": 0.6,
    "330": 0.6,
    "350": 0.6,
    "370": 0.6,
    "390": 0.6,
    "410": 0.6,
    "430": 0.6,
    "450": 0.6,
    "470": 0.6,
    "490": 0.5,
    "510": 0.5,
    "530": 0.5
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to calculate the transaction gas here:

https://legacy.ethgasstation.info/calculatorTxV.php

This is the best resource I have found so far on explaining the results (may have some missing):

https://github.com/ethgasstation/ethgasstation-api/blob/master/docs/v1.md